# How to process bigger gzipped files with Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, zip, gzip

Is it possible to process a huge (~3G) file with pure Ruby (1.8) using limited amount of RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the following would make sense:

```
 Zlib::GzipReader.open(file) { |gz|
   gz.each_line { |line|
     #do stuff
   }
   gz.close
 }
```

Let me know if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Zlib::GzipReader](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/classes/Zlib/GzipReader.html) to process it line by line using #each_line or #each_byte.